Flutter Web - Some svg file does not appear on Mobile device
I have a Flutter Web application, and in there, If I use web browser like google chrome or safari, even If I can resize it to small like mobile, I can see the SVG image fully.
On the other hand (Problem is starting here), after I open my app via website (I use iPhone 13), svg image does not appear.
I tried to convert it SVG TO JPEG and it worked, but I need SVG version of it.
By the way, I use flutter_svg package which is the popular one.
Also, note that I also use another SVG files which has a smaller dimension (like 25 height, 25 width), and smaller size (like 10kb) I can see all of them in my mobile phone although they are also a SVG file.
I tried to make it small the SVG which has a problem, even If I do it like 5 width 5 height, I could not see. So the problem is not a dimension of it. I do not have overflowed problems.
Also, for the sizes, SVG is 900kb, on the other hand jpeg is also approximately 900kb.
Finally, all the processes are controlled in release mode, debug mode, and production/live mode (unfortunately I have a problem there).

I solved it like that
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release --no-tree-shake-icons
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit

